# identifying words and phrases

Tags: american-english, listening

Have had a hard time  deciphering some words/phrases in a podcast. So i'd like to share one part that I found to be difficult, at least, for me.
https://voca.ro/1omVsJqG4SuY
Normally I hear it like "... we're feeling bored and lonely" but at a much lower speed it's like " if you're feeling", which makes more sense in the context.

Comment: She doesn't enunciate the words 'if you're feeling' at all, but it's obvious from the context that that is what she means.

Comment: thanks for response. so what does she actually say after the end of the previous sentence(" ... we like to volunteer"). Is it "we're feeling" or something else to your ears?

Comment: "If you're feeling bored or lonely, you can volunteer in a soup kitchen."